# Why cannot find mCurrentFocus or mFocusedApp in Huawei P30 EMUI 12?

Tags: adb, huawei-mobile-services

I am try to using the code below to get the current screen, but I cannot get what is the current screen of my phone.

```
adb dumpsys window windows | findstr mFocusedApp
```

or

```
adb dumpsys window windows | findstr mCurrentFocus
```

Anyone can exist me how to get the current screen?

Comment: If you mean the top activity name and package you can use https://stackoverflow.com/a/45174265/236465

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would like to share my final findings on this question. Sincerely hoping this can help those who faced the same problem in the future.

If you want to look through all the activities of your device , you may try the code below:

```
adb shell dumpsys activity
```

Here is the code that might help you to find the current screen activity, the main subject is `mLastResumedActivity`

```
adb shell dumpsys activity | findstr mLastResumedActivity
```